# PHP empty fields not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Can anyone find any errors in this script because I can still submit blank forms. The PHP empty() function also isn't working. I've tried double checking, triple checking and I can't find no simple explanation. I am working in a local environment using XAMPP. Any advice?

```
<?php
include('core/includes/startsite.inc.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "salvation", "dcstocksolutions");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
if($name == "" || $comment == ""){
    $msg = "Sorry, you missed out a field.";
}
$q = "INSERT INTO testimonials ('name', 'comment') VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";

if($con->query($q)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Thank you! Your review was submitted.";
    header("Location: testimonials?r=1");
} else {
    $msg = "Sorry, there was an error submitting your review, please try again later.";
}
}
?>
<div class="testimonial-container">
<h3 align="center">Leave a review</h3><br />
    <?php
        if(isset($msg)){
            echo("<p align=\"center\">" . $msg . "</p>");
        }
    ?>
    <form action="review" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Full Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment:</td>
                <td><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Review"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
include('core/includes/endsite.inc.php');
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any `empty()` function in your code!

Comment: I have used it and then removed it as it didn't work. I used empty here: `if(empty($name) || empty($comment))`

Comment: There are a couple of things to address regarding your code: 1 - `if(@$_POST)` I don't know what's that, maybe is an approach that I'm not familiar with, I use: `if($_POST)` or better the function `isset()` 2 - you aren't preventing **sql injections** 3 - after the `if` you're doing this: `$q = "INSERT INTO testimonials ('name', 'comment') VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";` with no `else`

Comment: What do you mean by you can submit blank forms? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this one. u don't have checked submit button here

```
<?php
include('core/includes/startsite.inc.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "salvation", "dcstocksolutions");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
if($name == "" || $comment == ""){
    $msg = "Sorry, you missed out a field.";
}else{
$q = "INSERT INTO testimonials ('name', 'comment') VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";

if($con->query($q)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Thank you! Your review was submitted.";
    header("Location: testimonials?r=1");
} else {
    $msg = "Sorry, there was an error submitting your review, please try again later.";
}
}else{echo "Not submited !";}}
?>
<div class="testimonial-container">
<h3 align="center">Leave a review</h3><br />
    <?php
        if(isset($msg)){
            echo("<p align=\"center\">" . $msg . "</p>");
        }
    ?>
    <form action="review" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Full Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment:</td>
                <td><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Review"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
include('core/includes/endsite.inc.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Harshana! I wasn't thinking haha. Thanks again.

Comment: you still need to apply a filter to the data from the `$_POST` super-global to ensure that it is safe, I suggest looking at the `filer_var` function on the PHP site. At least you are using mysqli :)